# Can't find wifi networks

Tags: python-3.x, sl4a

I am working on python sl4a script to scan wifi networks around me, search for specific SSID by partial match (network name is HOME1234 and script should find all networks which contain HOME), retrieve full network SSID from list by index and connect to it.

Problem is that function `Android().wifiGetScanResults()` returns variable of type `sl4a.result`. What i need it to do is to output this as list so algorithm can search trough every element and return its index.

This is algorithm: `number=[my_list.index(i) for i in my_list if "HOME" in i]`

my_list: List to search trough

HOME: Name of network to search for

This is code

```
from sl4a import * 
from time import * 

a=Android()

def find_net(): 
    try:
        print("Scanning")
        a.wifiLockAcquireFull() 
        a.wifiStartScan()
        sleep(5)
        print("Scan completed")
        aps=list(a.wifiGetScanResults())
        print("Got results")
        try:
            number=[aps.index(i) for i in aps if "HOM" in i]
        except:
            print("Nothing found")
            return number

    except:
        print("Scan Failed")

 print(find_net())
```

This code gives this result

```
Scanning
Scan completed
Got results
Nothing found
Scan Failed
None

#[QPython] Press enter to exit
```

**Please note that this is runned in qpython3 on android**

Comment: Have you try letting it scan longer, my network adapter need at least 6 seconds to find a network(it is a usb adapter). If you are farther away then 20 feet, try 12 seconds or more.

Comment: It has enough time. If i set it to only print results it gives me list with ssid bssid signal strength

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printing out everything is good!
Every sl4a call will return something like `Result(id=1, result=None, error=None)`, so I ran this:

```
import sl4a
droid=sl4a.Android()
print(droid.wifiLockAcquireFull())
print(droid.wifiStartScan())
print(droid.wifiGetScanResults())
```

And I got:

```
Result(id=1, result=None, error=None)
java.lang.NullPointerException: throw with null exception
Result(id=2, result=None, error='java.lang.NullPointerException: throw with null exception')
Result(id=3, result=[a list of dictionaries, each one is a wifi], error=None)
```

Looks like something went wrong when running `wifiStartScan`, I can't control it since it's in sl4a. Also, only calling `wifiGetScanResults` can still get the results since the [documentation](http://www.mithril.com.au/android/doc/WifiFacade.html) said `wifiGetScanResults` returns the list of access points found during "the most recent" Wifi scan and Android itself performs the scan frequently.

The results are a list of dictionaries, each one contains these keys: "capabilities", "frequency", "ssid", "bssid", "level".
So what you want may be:

```
import sl4a,time
droid = sl4a.Android()

### keep these if your phone can run wifiStartScan without errors ###
print("Scanning...")
droid.wifiLockAcquireFull()
droid.wifiStartScan()
time.sleep(5)
print("Scan completed")
### keep these if your phone can run wifiStartScan without errors ###

aps = droid.wifiGetScanResults().result
numbers = [i for i in range(len(aps)) if "HOME" in aps[i]["ssid"] ]
print(numbers)
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it doesn't give error anymore however now it gives empty result. Also if i try to print aps it is empty too.

Comment: Sorry for not being able to help you. Is the sl4a call's error=None?

Comment: Also, does your qpython3 hold ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission? Some useful links here: [sl4a WifiFacade source](https://github.com/damonkohler/sl4a/blob/d3c17dca978cbeee545e12ea240a9dbf2a6999e9/android/Common/src/com/googlecode/android_scripting/facade/WifiFacade.java) & [Android WifiManager Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults())

Comment: I switched to qpython but someone hacked my messenger account and i am currently in hurry

Comment: I saw both links and were somewhat helpful to see how it works behind the scenes. You were right app didn't hold ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION but giving it these permissions didn't help.

Comment: Well, then I don't know... Because the problem is inside sl4a, not in the Python script.

Comment: Thanks for help. I am working on workaround so i don't have to use that.

Comment: Good luck! I thought maybe I can try to debug through `adb logcat` or something like that, but if I find what the bug is, I can only send an issue to sl4a or rebuild it, which may not help. Using other stuff may be quicker.